# .Net MVC - Can't Stop my Ajax.BeginForm to be hacked

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have build an Ajax based form in my .Net MVC Web Application but I can't stop from being hacked and used to send me Spam messages.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactSend", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "Contact.submitOnBegin", OnSuccess = "Contact.submitOnSuccess" }, new { id = "contact-form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <input id="contact-cta" type="hidden" name="cta" value="@ViewBag.CTA" />

                <label class="form-label" for="nome">@Resources.Contact_Form_Name <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <div class="form-input-ctn">
                    <input id="contact-name" type="text" name="name">
                    <div class="mandatory-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</div>
                </div>
                <label class="form-label" for="email">@Resources.Contact_Form_Email <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <div class="form-input-ctn">
                    <input id="contact-email" type="text" name="email">
                    <div class="mandatory-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</div>
                    <div class="invalid-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Invalid</div>
                </div>
                <label class="form-label" for="phone">@Resources.Contact_Form_Phone <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <div class="form-input-ctn">
                    <input id="contact-phone" type="text" name="phone">
                    <div class="mandatory-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</div>
                    <div class="invalid-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Invalid</div>
                </div>
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Subject))
                {
                    <label class="form-label" for="subject">@Resources.Contact_Form_Subject</label>
                    <div class="form-input-ctn">
                        <input id="contact-subject" type="text" name="subject" value="@ViewBag.Subject">
                        <div class="mandatory-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</div>
                    </div>
                }
                <label class="form-label" for="message">@Resources.Contact_Form_Message <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <div class="form-input-ctn">
                    <textarea id="contact-message" class="form-textarea" name="message">@ViewBag.Message</textarea>
                    <div class="mandatory-error message-mandatory-error">@Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</div>
                </div>
                <label class="form-label"><span class="mandatory">*</span> @Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</label>
                <div class="form-input-ctn">
                    <div id="contact-recaptcha-mandatory-error" class="recaptcha-mandatory">@Resources.Contact_Form_Mandatory</div>
                    <div id="contact-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="reCaptchaOnValidCallback"></div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <input id="contact-submit-btn" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="@Resources.Contact_Form_Send_Button" data-sending-message="@Resources.Contact_Form_Sending_Button">
            }
```

I have also included the Google reCaptcha but nothing changed.

In my Contact.submitOnBegin jQuery code I do all the validation to avoid blank values and invalid values:

```
var _submitOnBegin = function () {

    _isFormValid();

    if (isFormValid) {
        $submitBtn.prop('disabled', true);

        var sendingMessage = $submitBtn.data("sending-message");
        $submitBtn.addClass("submitting");
        $submitBtn.val(sendingMessage);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

And in the isFormValid funcion, I do all the tests for each input:

```
var _isFormValid = function () {

    // Reset
    isFocusOn = false;
    isFormValid = true;

    // Name
    if ($contactName.val() == "") {
        _showErrorMessage($contactName, contactErrorMandatoryCls);
    }
 
    // Email
    if ($contactEmail.val() == "") {
        _showErrorMessage($contactEmail, contactErrorMandatoryCls);
    }
    else if (!_isEmailValid()) {
        _showErrorMessage($contactEmail, contactErrorInvalidCls);
    }

    // Phone
    if ($contactPhone.val() == "") {
        _showErrorMessage($contactPhone, contactErrorMandatoryCls);
    }
    else if (!_isPhoneValid()) {
        _showErrorMessage($contactPhone, contactErrorInvalidCls);
    }

    // Message
    if ($contactMessage.val() == "") {
        _showErrorMessage($contactMessage, contactErrorMandatoryCls);
    }

    // reCaptcha
    var reCaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    if (reCaptchaResponse.length == 0) {
        isFormValid = false;
        $("#contact-recaptcha-mandatory-error").addClass(contactErrorRecaptchaMandatoryCls);
    }
};
var _reCaptchaRender = function () {
    grecaptcha.render('contact-recaptcha', {
        'sitekey': 'XXX'
    });
};
var _reCaptchaValid = function () {
    $contactRecaptchaMandatoryError.removeClass(contactErrorRecaptchaMandatoryCls);
};

var _showErrorMessage = function (el, msg) {
    el.addClass(contactErrorMandatoryCls);
    el.parent().find("." + msg).fadeIn();

    if (!isFocusOn) {
        el.focus();
        isFocusOn = true;
    }
    isFormValid = false;
};
```

More stranged is that they are able to hack the form with the reCaptcha and also to send empty values in the subject for example.

And in the Contact.SubmitOnSuccess I do the submission if everything is ok:

```
var _submitOnSuccess = function (ajaxResult) {

    sentResultOk = ajaxResult.Success;

    $sentModal.load("/home/contactsent?cta=" + $contactCTA.val(), function () {
        if (sentResultOk == true) {
            $("#" + sentModalOkId).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + sentModalErrorId).show();
        }

        $sentModal.fadeIn(function () {
            $contactForm[0].reset();
            grecaptcha.reset();
            $submitBtn.removeClass("submitting");
            $submitBtn.prop('disabled', false);
            $submitBtn.val("Enviar");
        });
    });
```

Comment: In your server-side code, where do you validate the reCaptcha result?  I'm only seeing client-side code here.

Comment: @David Hi, I don't do anything since the form never goes to server side until it's valid and from the docs I saw in Google documentation, I was convinced that I can do the validation only from client-side.

Comment: If you're relying on the client to tell you whether or not it's valid then that explains why it's being hacked.  The hacker is simply telling you that it's valid.  You have to [verify the user's response with Google](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) to validate that they did in fact solve the captcha and aren't just telling you that they did.

Comment: @David thanks, I will check it. BTW how it's possible to pass hover all my script validation and AntiForgeryToken Key?

Comment: The client isn't required to execute JavaScript, or even be interacting with this in a web browser.  They can send any request that they like to your server.  It's up to your *server-side* code to validate that request.  Never trust anything that comes from the client.

Comment: @David so in this case I should make the "filter" from Spam and Genuine using the reCaptcha only after the form is submitted and in the server-side. And from a client-side point of view, JavaScript is only needed to Genuine access.

Comment: Basically when the user submits the form to the server, that form should include the reCaptcha response token.  In the server-side code you would validate the form (return an error if invalid), then validate the token with Google (return an error if invalid), then if everything's valid you process the form.

Comment: @David when you say return an error if invalid, in this case, if the validation is false, it's certainly because it has been hacked correct? Or else, if it's a genuine user, it will never reach the server invalid.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  It's up to you how to handle any given error.  Maybe client-side validation had a bug, maybe there's a connection problem for reCaptcha for a moment, etc.  You don't need to assume that the user is doing something malicious, just handle validation appropriately.  So if they're not doing something malicious, they see a helpful error.  And if they are doing something malicious, *all* they see is a helpful error.

Comment: @David ok thanks. Please feel free to publish your answer so I can rate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't stop from being hacked and used to send me Spam messages

The core of the problem is reflected in a comment on the question:

> the form never goes to server side until it's valid and from the docs I saw in Google documentation, I was convinced that I can do the validation only from client-side

What's happening is that you're relying on the client to tell the server that everything is valid.  So any hacker can simply... tell the server that everything is valid.

Never implicitly trust what comes from the client.  Always validate.

For reCaptcha, Google returns to your client-side code with a token and you would [validate that token from your server-side code](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).  Remember that the validation of this token is done in the **same** server-side operation as processing the form.  After all, if you first have the client send the token to the server and get a valid/invalid response and *then* send the form to the server then you're back in the same place as before... The client can just send the form to the server and claim that it was valid.

Without getting too deep into examples, the overall flow should be:

1. User performs reCaptcha, your client-side code gets a token from Google.
2. Client-side code validates the form before posting to the server.  (This is not a security step, this is just for UX so the user doesn't have to wait for a server response for validation.)
3. User posts the form to the server.  This includes all form data **and** the reCaptcha token that your client-side code received from Google.
4. Server-side code validates the form.  This is essentially the same validation as step 2 above, just double-checking it since you can't assume the data is valid.
5. Server-side code validates the reCaptcha token with Google.
6. If everything checks out, process the form and continue with the application flow.

Any step that fails, you'd handle that error however you see fit.  In most cases you'd just return some error response back to the client, either by redirecting to an error page or by returning an AJAX error and handling it gracefully in client-side code.  You don't need to assume that any error is because of a hacking attempt.  Just show a friendly error, that's all.  As long as the attacker can't get any further, it doesn't matter to them what the error says.